# Laravel Trying to get property '' of non-object error

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am getting an error. I have shared the necessary code below. When I add kernel code, this error goes away and it works fine, but it causes other errors to not appear. What do you think could be the problem?

```
class TrendyolController extends Controller
{
    public $baseUrl;
    public $guzzle;
    public $businessId;
    public $marketplaceSettings;
    public $authentication;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Set base url
        $this->baseUrl = env('TRENDYOL_BASE_URL');

        // Set guzzle
        $this->guzzle = new Client();

        // Set business id
        $this->businessId = Session::get('user.business_id');

        // Set marketplace settings
        $this->marketplaceSettings = Business::find($this->businessId);

        // Set authentication
        $this->authentication = base64_encode($this->marketplaceSettings
            ->trendyolExternalKey1 . ':' .
            $this->marketplaceSettings->trendyolExternalKey2);
    }
}
```

**Error**

[image]

Comment: `dd($this->marketplaceSettings)` before use this and check it getting any value or not.

Comment: takes value. there doesn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: its a data of an object or an array?